# Как отображать выбранный пункт RecyclerView вверху экрана?

Tags: android, recyclerview

В боковом меню с десяток пунктов, нажатие на каждый из них вызывает метод:recyclerView.scrollToPosition(position);
Если нажимаем в боковом меню в порядке возрастания (1 -10), то при прокрутке списка к нужному элементу, это элемент отображается внизу экрана.
А если нажимаем (10 - 1), то элемент списка отображается вверху экрана.

Как сделать чтобы при переходе к выбранному элементу он всегда отображался вверху экрана?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
 public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.nav_people) {
        recyclerView.scrollToPosition(position);
```

---

```
public class CommandAdapter extends SectionedRecyclerViewAdapter<CommandAdapter.ViewHolder> {
private CharSequence[][] arrayComand;
String[] section;
TypedArray icons;

public CommandAdapter(CharSequence[][] arrayComand, String[] section, TypedArray icons) {
    this.arrayComand = arrayComand;
    this.section = section;
    this.icons = icons;
}

@Override
public int getSectionCount() {
    return arrayComand.length;
}

@Override
public int getItemCount(int section) {
    return arrayComand[section].length;
}

@Override
public void onBindHeaderViewHolder(CommandAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int section) {
    holder.title.setText(this.section[section]);
    holder.viewIcon.setImageResource(icons.getResourceId(section, -1));
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(CommandAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int section, int relativePosition, int absolutePosition) {
    holder.tvDescription.setText(arrayComand[section][relativePosition]);
}

@Override
public CommandAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    int layout;
    switch (viewType) {
        case VIEW_TYPE_HEADER:
            layout = R.layout.list_item_header;
            break;
        case VIEW_TYPE_ITEM:
            layout = R.layout.item;
            break;
        default:
            layout = R.layout.list_item_header;
            break;
    }

    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(layout, parent, false);
    return new ViewHolder(v);
}


public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public TextView tvDescription;
    public TextView title;
    private ImageView viewIcon;

    public ViewHolder(View v) {
        super(v);
        title = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.title);
        tvDescription = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tv_description);
        viewIcon = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.ivIcon);
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Возможно это поможет Вам, у LinearLayoutManager есть метод:

```
layoutManager.scrollToPositionWithOffset(index, offset);
```

нужно указать offset = 0

Comment: Благодарю, то что доктор прописал.